# why couldn't I find the python module uwsgi after pip install uwsgi?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

After I have installed the uwsgi, I add the following code:

```
import uwsgi
```

But the IDE is warning that uwsgi module not exist.

the command I used to install the uwsgi is:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

the installed uwsgi package is:

```
pip freeze | grep -i uwsgi
uWSGI==2.0.19.1
```

but in the site-packages dir there is not any uwsgi subdir.

Comment: Your ide may use a different python, run: import sys and print(sys.path) in both terminal and IDE, then you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.x you may need to use pip3.

```
pip3 install uwsgi
```

And restart the Kernal.